# System-versioned tables: need historical data for a new empty table for testing / development

Tags: mariadb

I want to track the changes of a table using MariaDB system versioning.

For these changes I need to create a visualization group by monthly changes.

How can I create test data inside the database table to test my query properly? It is a new empty database table, so I need to create test data in the past. I am not able to wait for a year or so to get proper test data.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of loading data need to change the current time like:

```
set statement timestamp=unix_timestamp('2021-03-04') for
insert into .....
```

ref: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=a9878a848bc8cd8b478842473294a446)

As [documented](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/system-versioned-tables/#system_versioning_asof), you cannot set `system_versioned_asof` to change the result of DML like [fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=4e7477fc5e48eb1c1dd975ae4d20bc4d).

Comment: sorry but the example seems not to work for me. 

I've created another example that shows the problem.

ref: [fiddle example with row_start, row_end](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=22d857c4dfc0c195b3d1a0d949440216)

Comment: Quite right, sorry, majorly changed the answer now.

Comment: Remember to recreate the order of INSERT or UPDATE statements depending on your data. If you start with an empty table, check with a SELECT COUNT(*) ... FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF TIMESTAMP(ROW_START) WHERE ... first whether you really need to insert or rather update.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with 10.11 MariaDB allows direct insertion of historical data.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/system-versioned-tables/#system_versioning_insert_history

```
system_versioning_insert_history
Description: Allows direct inserts into ROW_START and ROW_END columns if secure_timestamp allows changing timestamp.
Commandline: --system-versioning-insert-history[={0|1}]
Scope: Global, Session
Dynamic: Yes
Type: Boolean
Default Value: OFF
Introduced: MariaDB 10.11.0
```